# Open tapped links in UITextView without html

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I've been working with Texture(former AsyncDisplayKit) for quite long time and got used to being able to easily make phone numbers and links clickable in ASTextNode.

Then I switched to an old xamarin project and needed the same feature there. I was struggling with finding the right and easy solution for this one and found out that people suggest working with UIWebView and stuff like that.

It's a little bit tricky, so I'll try to describe some steps I've come up with while solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try parse your string for possible links.  In my case the string is
  always a set of phone numbers like - "88002000600 +7999999999
  8888800888" so it's an easy case, but it should not be a problem to
  parse for web site links, emails by regex.
- Make up attributed string and assign necessary attributes like this

--

```
//something right here and get your potential links list
    var attributedContacts = new NSMutableAttributedString (value as string, UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (14), UIColor.White, UIColor.Clear);
                foreach (var item in numbers) {
                    var nsStringItem = new NSString (item);
                    var nsTelPromptLink = new NSString (string.Format ("telprompt://{0}", item));
                    var range = attributedContacts.MutableString.LocalizedStandardRangeOfString (nsStringItem);
                    attributedContacts.AddAttribute (new NSString ("TextLinkAttributeName"), nsTelPromptLink, range);
                }
                textView.AttributedText = attributedContacts;
```

- Then you should add a gesture recognizer to your text view and handle
  taps the following way:

--

```
var tapRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer ((UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer) => {
                var textView = recognizer.View as UITextView;
                if (textView == null)
                    return;
                var tappedPoint = recognizer.LocationInView (textView);
                tappedPoint.X -= textView.TextContainerInset.Left;
                tappedPoint.Y -= textView.TextContainerInset.Top;
                var layoutManager = textView.LayoutManager;
                nfloat tmp = 0;
                var tappedCharacterIndex = layoutManager.CharacterIndexForPoint (tappedPoint, textView.TextContainer, ref tmp);
                NSRange range = new NSRange ();
                var url = textView.AttributedText.GetAttribute ("TextLinkAttributeName", (nint)tappedCharacterIndex, out range) as NSString;
                if (url == null)
                    return;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (new NSUrl (url.ToString ()));
            });

            ContactsTextView.AddGestureRecognizer (tapRecognizer);
```

So, it's rather rough solution and there should be additional checks but I think the idea itself is pretty clear. It can easily be applied to native solutions in Swift or Objective-C.